# How to remove all items from nested list while iterating in C#

Tags: c#

I have a nested list that contains

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

The list can be used like:

```
    var Persons = new List<Person>();
    Persons.Add(new Person("Eric"));
    Persons[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
    Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Tom"));
    Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("John"));
    Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
    Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Bill"));
    Persons.Add(new Person("John");
```

How can I iterate over the list `Persons` and remove all items with the name "John"? If the name is John the node with the name John and all underlaying subitems should be removed.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you trying to achieve.

Comment: its a simple link list program please check the link it might solve your problem
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/linked-list-implementation-in-c-sharp/

Comment: This might be relevant for you [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417246/filtering-lists-using-linq)

Comment: Is it a tree? Do the children have children again?

Comment: @Markus Yes it is a tree. Children have children again.

Comment: If a person has the name "John", do you want to remove the whole subtree?

Comment: @Markus I want to remove the node with the name John and the whole underlaying subtree.

Comment: do you want to search only the parent node for the name john or the inner ones as well?

Comment: Call a clear on the child list of the relevant list index(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive method that removes all persons with the specified name. You can call it like `RemoveAllWithName(Persons, "John");`.

```
private void RemoveAllWithName(List<Person> people, string name)
{
    for(int i = people.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        Person person = people[i];
        if(person.Name == name) {
            people.RemoveAt(i);
        } else if(person.Childs != null) {
            RemoveAllWithName(person.Childs, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it remove the underlaying subtree too? If a Person has the name "John" that Person and the whole underlaying sub-tree should be removed.

Comment: Do you mean his children? His children are removed together with the person "John". To answer your question: YES.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off not removing the elements from the existing structure but instead to return a new structure without the "John"'s.

Here's how:

```
List<Person> Except(List<Person> people, string name) =>
    people
        .Where(p => p.Name != name)
        .Select(p => new Person(p.Name)
        {
            Childs = Except(p.Childs ?? new List<Person>(), name) // Case typo in method name
        })
        .ToList();
```

If you start with your original data:

```
var Persons = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person("Eric")
    {
        Childs = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Tom"),
            new Person("John")
            {
                Childs = new List<Person>()
                {
                    new Person("Bill")
                }
            }
        }
    },
    new Person("John")
};
```

You can now run this:

```
List<Person> PersonsNotJohn = Except(Persons, "John");
```

That gives:

[image: PersonsNotJohn]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Add Namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

Use the below one liner

```
Persons.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == "John");
```

Comment: What happens when a John is a child? :)

Comment: That doesn't remove the "inner" John, only the "outer".

Comment: This wasn't required. Was it @Bob?

Comment: @GaganDeep It wasn't.

Comment: The the above solution works perfectly. Have you tried @Bob?

Comment: If you need to search the name John in the children as well then you need to do it through recursion @Bob.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would get a downvote, it removes all 'direct' people with the name "John", children of that node will no longer be part of list `persons` either, as they are only found in the list by association to `John`. Also as noted, it's not a requirement to remove children named `John`, just people named `John`, directly in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Persons = new List<Person>();
        Persons.Add(new Person("Eric"));
        Persons[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
        Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Tom"));
        Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("John"));
        Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
        Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Bill"));
        Persons.Add(new Person("John"));
        RemoveAllWithName("John", Persons);
        Persons.ForEach(x=>Print(x));
    }
    private static void RemoveAllWithName(string name, List<Person> persons)
    {
        if (persons != null && persons.Any())
        {
            persons.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == name);
        }
        if (persons != null && persons.Any())
        {
            persons.ForEach(x => RemoveAllWithName(name, x.Childs));
        }
    }
    private static void Print(Person person)
    {
        if (person != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
            person.Childs?.ForEach(Print);
        }
    }
```